# Augeas: How to match dash?

Tags: regex, escaping, augeas

Want to write a lens for duply-exclude Files. Example:

```
+ /etc
- /
```

So my lens looks like this:

```
module DuplyExclude =
  let nl = del /[\n]+/ "\n"
  let entry = [ label "entry" . [ label "op" . store /(\+|-)/ ] . del /[ \t]+/ " " . [ label "path" . store /\/[^ \t\n\r]+/ ] ]
  let lns = ( entry . nl )*

  test lns get "+ /hello\n+ /etc\n- /" = ?
```

This results in an error. I know from experimenting a bit, that the regular expression `/(\+|-)/` does not match the second line. The question is: Why the dash seems to be not matchable, even if escaped by `\`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons for this:

1. The test string is missing a trailing `\n`.  This is important as `lns` is defined as having an entry followed by an unconditional new line.  Note that this only really affects string tests with augparse because when loading files via the library, it adds a trailing \n to any file read in (since many lenses can't handle a missing EOL).
2. The path node is defined as matching a single `/` followed by at least one (`+`) other character in `store /\/[^ \t\n\r]+/`.  This won't match a single `/` entry.

So with these two changes, this lens works:

```
module DuplyExclude =
  let nl = del /[\n]+/ "\n"
  let entry = [ label "entry" . [ label "op" . store /(\+|-)/ ] . del /[ \t]+/ " " . [ label "path" . store /\/[^ \t\n\r]*/ ] ]
  let lns = ( entry . nl )*

  test lns get "+ /hello\n+ /etc\n- /\n" = ?
```

```
Test result: /tmp/duplyexclude.aug:6.2-.44:
  { "entry"
    { "op" = "+" }
    { "path" = "/hello" }
  }
  { "entry"
    { "op" = "+" }
    { "path" = "/etc" }
  }
  { "entry"
    { "op" = "-" }
    { "path" = "/" }
  }
```